# How to display images(not attachment) in the body from an email using imap in PHP

Tags: php, imap

Currently, I am using `imap_fetchbody()` to fetch the content, but images in the body are not coming in the response.

It's coming like

```
<img id="_x0000_i1026" src="cid:image003.jpg@01D30606.B8EB5FC0" width="867" height="1115">
```

which is not the visible or wrong path of the image.

Comment: Read the comments from official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php#42633